# Getting Parser already accessed issue while calling https endpoint

Tags: java, https, axis, apache-axis

I am invoking one soap API deployed on JBoss instance from one of my java based application which uses Axis2. When I hit the URL with http, it just works fine, but when I change the URL to https with its port it throws Parser already accessed error.

I have already included the certificates to jre cacerts file, but still the issue. Below is the error stack for same.

```
  org.apache.axis2.AxisFault caught:
postSchedule probably timed out. Exception caught: problem accessing the parser. Parser already accessed!
problem accessing the parser. Parser already accessed!
    org.apache.axis2.AxisFault.makeFault(AxisFault.java:417)
    org.apache.axis2.transport.http.SOAPMessageFormatter.writeTo(SOAPMessageFormatter.java:72)
    org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisRequestEntity.writeRequest(AxisRequestEntity.java:84)
    org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.EntityEnclosingMethod.writeRequestBody(EntityEnclosingMethod.java:495)
    org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.writeRequest(HttpMethodBase.java:1973)
    org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.execute(HttpMethodBase.java:993)
    org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry(HttpMethodDirector.java:397)
    org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeMethod(HttpMethodDirector.java:170)
    org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:396)
    org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:346)
    org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AbstractHTTPSender.executeMethod(AbstractHTTPSender.java:520)
    org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender.sendViaPost(HTTPSender.java:191)
    org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender.send(HTTPSender.java:77)
    org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender.writeMessageWithCommons(CommonsHTTPTransportSender.java:327)
    org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender.invoke(CommonsHTTPTransportSender.java:206)
    org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.send(AxisEngine.java:396)
    org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:374)
    org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:211)
    org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:163)
```